# Firefox corners displayed as solid when curved dotted

Tags: css, firefox, web

I used the CSS border radius to curve a dotted border. It looks great in every browser except firefox where only the corners have a solid curve. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a minimal code that shows the problem in Firefox and works in the other browsers?

Comment: It is an old bug, still unfixed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago this was a bug of FireFox as far as I remember. Not sure how it's now.

Show us your CSS please. Maybe you have to use browser specific CSS like this:

```
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
```

Also there can be some dependency of what HTML version you use. HTML 5 hope :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Firefox renders it.
There is no solution for this.
http://jsfiddle.net/437sp/

```
.border {
    width:200px;
    height: 50px;
    border:5px dotted green;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```